How to create a new dataframe based on date in pandas
I created a dataframe from CSV's where I had the date in milis. I managed to turn this into a date, exactly what I want. However, when I try to create a new dataframe with a seperate date, this does not work. I use the standard .loc for pandas as was recommended on this site.
I have the following code:
samen['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(samen['timestamp'], unit='ms')
samen['timestamp'] = samen['timestamp'].dt.date


dag1 = samen.loc[samen["timestamp"] ==  "2019-05-08" ] 
dag1

However, when I use this code, it returns an empty dataframe. I am not sure where the fault lies.

.dt.date converts to datetime.date, which Pandas doesn't support natively.
Instead, you could keep using Pandas datetime objects, but zero out the times using .dt.normalize() — that is, assuming the times aren't midnight already. Then the comparison will work as expected.

samen['timestamp'].dt.date converts the timestamp to a datetime.date object, but in your filtering condition you are using a string. So you should convert "2019-05-08" to date:
dag1 = samen.loc[samen["timestamp"] == pd.to_datetime("2019-05-08").date()]


Unfortunately, datetime.date are stored as object dtype, which isn't ideal. I posted my own answer with a more idiomatic approach (normalized datetimes).
